# The DB2 stored procedure that runs automatically not triggered

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I have a stored procedure created some time ago, actually in 2016 and it is set to run every year in the first day. The procedure automatically ran in 2017.01.01 but now in 2018 this did not happened automatically and i had to trigger it manually. Do you have any hints of what can i check to see what went wrong?
Below you can find the requested details:

DB2 server operating system: Linux ; 
DB2 version: 10.1.3.0 ; 
Scheduler: I am using cron.

1. I have checked the ADMIN_TASK_LIST and the END_TIME column is NULL, so from my point of view this should never stop running;
   2.On first of January there is no entry for this in 2018, only in 2017;
2. I will check the files and let you know ;
3. I don't find any ATS_TASK_LIST, do you mean ADMIN_TASK_LIST?

---

I have checked db2diag and there was a space error identified but as per my colleagues feedback should have nothing to do with this. Also, i want to mention that yesterday we have created a test task which was set to be executed today at a certain hour and was not triggered. I have attached an image with the TEST task details in order for you to see if there is anything set wrong. Also, here is the error that i was talking about:"The Event Monitor "DB2DETAILDEADLOCK" has reached its file capacity"

[TEST TASK IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7SsG.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question to add missing details, which scheduler you are using, and your Db2 version and Db2-server operating-system (Z/OS, OS/400, Linux, AIX, Windows etc).

Comment: Edit your question to add the *scheduler* details, are you using cron, or the Db2 Admininstative Task Scheduler, or some other scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't know what schedules your job.

If cron is the scheduler (as you originally wrote), then most likely your question has nothing to do with Db2, see checks at the end of this answer. If you lack the skills with cron, ask your linux admin or study the docs and there's plenty of online info.

If the Db2 Administrative Task Scheduler (ATS)is the scheduler (as you subsequently imply from your comments), then the problem can be with Db2.  Cron has nothing to do with the ATS, they are unrelated.  So then your question is "why did ATS not run my job". This is also often asked.

Suggested checks for ATS jobs.

1. Check if the job is still present in ADMIN_TASK_LIST with correct definition , especially the END_TIME column.
2. Check if there is an entry in ADMIN_TASK_STATUS for this job on 01-January and study the entry for details of why the job failed
3. If the job is present in ADMIN_TASK_LIST with correct definition, and if    there is no entry for the job in ADMIN_TASK_STATUS then  check if the    db2acd is still running, and check if db2acd has run  out of  memory (evidence in db2diag). I have seen that stopping    db2acd cures    this problem (Db2 watchdog will immediately restart  db2acd).
4. If you are still stuck then edit your question to show the ATS_TASK_LIST entry and the ADMIN_TASK_STATUS entry for the failed run.  Take care to give accurate responses to requests for clarification.

============================================

If cron is the scheduler, the advice below applies:

It is likely that your question is "why did cron not run my job".

That is a frequently asked question, so you can research that (there are many pages giving advice on that topic).

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged

Check the crontab entry to ensure it is still valid.

Check the cron entry command (usually a script) still exists, and has
the correct permissions and that it can run with the 
account specified .

Investigate the cron log file (if that is still available) and study that file
for clues . This will show if cron attempted to start the job, and what the exit code was.

When cron fails to run a job and that job had some output, cron emails the crontab owner  with the output of the failed job. 
But this can depend on the exact command that is in the cron entry
(in case it redirects stdout and stderr to some file instead, in
which case you should consult that file).
If the cron entry does not redirect stdout/stderr, and the script/command gives output when run then refer to the mailbox of the cron owner to see what emails arrived on first of january.

Comment: Thank you! I will proceed with my investigation using your recommendations. I will get back once i will have an update.

Comment: I have checked the cron/messages logs as recommended in the link you have provided and no error was identified. My next step is to verify cron on the server in order to see how the configuration is defined.

Comment: I have tried to check also on the server but is really hard for me to do this since i do not know for what exactly should I search for. All I can tell you is that when the procedure was created, the task was inserted in the table SYSTOOLS.ADMIN_TASK_LIST. I do not remember to do any other configures on the server in order to configure the execution of the task.